# Configure ports in WebStorm - React + Node Express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webstorm, react-fullstack

I am going to do a fullstack implementation with WebStorm IDE. I use react.js and node-express for this. I can do this in separate projects. But I want to know how to implement both backend and frontend in WebStorm project while configuring ports.

When starting the frontend we can give start html file in package.json file under `"start": "parcel index.html"`. When starting backend we can give `"node app.js"` But this can be done when we are doing the implementation in two different projects.

But if we are doing both frontend and backend how can I start react part and node-express part on two different ports? For example:
- react app > localhost:1234
- node-express > localhost:3000

```
"start": "parcel index.html"
"start": "node app.js"
```

// in package.json we can set only one `start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package like [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) to achieve this. Install it then have two separate scripts (like start-front-end and start-server) in your package.json that npm-run-all runs both of e.g.

```
"scripts": {
  "start-front-end": "parcel index.html --open",
  "start-server": "node app.js",
  "start": "npm-run-all start-server start-front-end",
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. @Tom The first two can be run and start both seperately. 
But when running the 3rd line without running the 1st two, the frontend does not start.

Comment: Can you list the contents of your scripts block? Also, what is the output on the command line from each of the individual commands?

Comment: `"main": "server.js",   
 "scripts": {  
"start-server": "node server.js",  
"start-front-end": "parcel ./public/index.html --open",   
"start": "npm-run-all start-server start-front-end" },  `

Comment: start-server > this will start the backend if I run it individually using the WebStorm's run button.
start-front-end > this will start the frontend and open up the html page in browser if I run it individually using the WebStorm's run button.
start > this will run only the backend and runs good. But does not allows to start the frontend or does not generate the front-end localhost link in the terminal. Even I browse the url in browser the page cannot be found.

Comment: This may specifically be a Webstorm issue then. Have you tried running `npm start` in a normal terminal?